# Is there a way to show warning for multiple required inputs that are left empty simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, alert, required

In JavaScript (used in React), while using inputs, I used the "required" prop in some inputs in a form. However, when multiple fields are left empty, the warning only shows up in the first required input that was left empty.

[image: 3 sample inputs with required prop]

The code for the same:

```
<form method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="" action="">
    <input length="20" required=""></input>
    <input length="20" required=""></input>
    <input length="20" required=""></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

I tried to change the required prop to manually handling the empty inputs but when the forms are really long, it's not practical. Is there a way I can show the same warning for every field that is left empty?

Thanks

Comment: The built in HTML form validator will only show the first error. If you want to show all errors you'll need to implement your own logic to detect those errors and report them in the UI. This is not a trivial configuration/HTML change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React, you may use useState hook to store input value of your inputs and render warnings for each empty input.

For example:

```
  const [inputA, setInputA] = useState('');
  const [inputB, setInputB] = useState('');
  const [inputC, setInputC] = useState('');

  const handleAChange = (event) => {
    setInputA(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleBChange = (event) => {
    setInputB(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleCChange = (event) => {
    setInputC(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        Input A:
        <input type="text" value={inputA} onChange={handleAChange} />
      </label>
      <p>Input A: {inputA}</p>
      {!inputA && <p>Cannot be empty!</p>}
      <label>
        Input B:
        <input type="text" value={inputB} onChange={handleBChange} />
      </label>
      <p>Input B: {inputB}</p>
      {!inputB && <p>Cannot be empty!</p>}
      <label>
        Input C:
        <input type="text" value={inputC} onChange={handleCChange} />
      </label>
      <p>Input C: {inputC}</p>
      {!inputC && <p>Cannot be empty!</p>}
    </form>
  );
```

This code will display a warning for each empty input. You could also use absolute positioning and z-index in css to make these warning look more like what you had whith *required* attribute.

You may aslo keep *required* attribute for accessibility though.